# How to extract innermost pair of tags using RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to extract a row from HTML table which contains some substring `XXX`:

```
<some html>
<tr rn="1"...AAA...</tr><tr rn="2"...XXX...</tr><tr rn="3"...ZZZ...</tr>
<some html>
```

`...` may contain attributes of `tr` and other elements but can't contain other `<tr>` tags. Surrounding HTML code contains other tables but they don't have `rn` attribute immediately after `<tr>`. I need to get the whole HTML code of the row and specifically value of `rn`:

```
Match 1: <tr rn="2" XXX </tr>
Match 2: 2
```

Obviously this RE works incorrectly, cause it extracts also the first row:

```
(<tr rn=\"(\d+)\".*XXX.*?tr>)
```

I tried to add negative lookahead in that ways:

```
(<tr rn(?!<tr rn)=\"(\d+)\".*XXX.*?tr>)
(<tr rn((?!<tr rn).)*=\"(\d+)\".*XXX.*?tr>)
```

But they also work incorrectly.
How do I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do this, but this should work:

```
(<tr rn=\"(\d+)\"(?:(?!tr>).)*?XXX.*?tr>)
```

Basically, you're adding a non-capturing group saying **anything that isn't `tr>`** (your closing tag) for as few repetitions as possible until you find the `XXX`.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Yeah, thanks! It's easy to understand when it works :)

Comment: +1, but in most flavors you won't need to escape the double quotes, nor to use the outer parentheses.